# How to update row in SQL server using linked MySql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, triggers, linked-server

I created linked server between `sql server and mysql`.It will work fine for me.
My question is when insert row in mysql table that time i want to update row in sql server table,

Like in mysql table name 'abc' when in this table new row insert that time in ms sql server table name is `xyz` and in this field name `status` by default true and when new row insert in the `abc` table that time in `xyz` table field name `status` will automatically update and status will change to false.

My linked server name is `MYLINK` and it will work fine for me , I want to `create trigger which update row` in sql server,and how to create trigger for update row in the ms sql server.

Comment: The question probably interesting, but I think you will have to edit it in order to make things *much* more clear if you want accurate answers.

Answer (score 1):

mysql cannot trigger anything else but mssql.
But you can use SQL Agent to schedule a task, executed on sql server to select data from the linked mysql

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [TriggerLocalServerTable]
   ON  dbo.[LocalServerTable]
    FOR INSERT
AS 

DECLARE @A varchar(4)
DECLARE @B varchar(4)
DECLARE @id int

BEGIN
 SELECT
 @A = A,
 @B = B,
 @id = id
 FROM inserted

 UPDATE  [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[Table]
 SET A = @A, B = @B
 WHERE id = @id      
END
```